# JW Player read from php cannot read video dynamically

Tags: php, video, jwplayer

I am trying to use JWPlayer to play videos on my website. But I cannot get the video served from php dynamically as I'm getting the following error:

```
Error loading media: File could not be played
```

My current code is:

```
<?php
   include('connection.php');//connect to db
   $id = $_GET['id'];//get video id from param
   $video = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM video_table WHERE id = '$id'");//video row from db
   $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($video);
   $ext = pathinfo($data['video_name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $file_name = $id . "." . $ext;
   echo $file_name;
?>
   <div id="container1"></div>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer('container1').setup({
                'id': 'container1',
                'type': '<?php echo $ext ?>',
                'wmode': 'transparent',
                'flashplayer': 'jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf',
                'file': 'video.php',
                'provider': 'video',
                'width': '480',
                'height': '320',
            });
        </script>
   </div>
```

**video.php**

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $video = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM video_table WHERE id = '$id'");
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($video);
    $ext = pathinfo($data['video_name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $type = pathinfo($data['type'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $file_name = $id . "." . $ext;//set the file name as saved in upload directory e.g: 1.mp4

    header("pragma : no-cache");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: $type");
    header("Content-Location: upload/$file_name");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize("upload/$file_name"));
    readfile("upload/$file_name");
?>
```

However, if I changed the absolute name here `(upload/1.mp4) instead of (upload/$file_name)` it works and video is provided. How can I get the video dynamically from parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
'provider': 'video',
```

To:

```
'type': 'mp4',
```

If you are using FLV instead of MP4, make it:

```
'type': 'flv',
```

Also:

A few things here. You still have provider set to video, I would remove that. Also you are pulling file in as video.php, but there is no ID set. Right now you are using - 'file': 'video.php', I would change it to video.php?id=1, also I would update from 6.4 to 6.6.

Comment: I have 'type': '<?php echo $ext ?>', which results to the video type (mp4 or flv). I'm still getting the same error. I have tried removing provider, or change to type:mp4, but I'm getting the same error

Comment: Here is a link of a sample app that uses the same code above http://fareed.comule.com/PhpProject1/view.php?id=1

Comment: if you can see video.php is retrieving the video file successfully on : http://fareed.comule.com/PhpProject1/video.php?id=1 but serving it to jw player yields in error

Comment: A few things here. You still have provider set to video, I would remove that. Also you are pulling file in as video.php, but there is no ID set. Right now you are using - 'file': 'video.php', I would change it to video.php?id=1, also I would update from 6.4 to 6.6